# PDO Login System not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I know I'll get a bunch of down-votes, but I am new to PDO and need to make a login system for a little web application. I can't seem to get it right:

```
<?php

include 'Config.php';

$username      = strtolower($_POST['username']);
$password      = md5($_POST['password']);
$hidden        = $_POST['hidden'];
$submit        = $_POST['submit'];
$host          = $config['mysql']['host'];
$mysql_user    = $config['mysql']['user'];
$mysql_pass    = $config['mysql']['pass'];
$db            = $config['mysql']['db'];

if(isset($username) && isset($password) && isset($submit) && !isset($hidden)) {

    try {
        $opt = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $objDatabase = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $opt);
        $objQuery    = $objDatabase->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
        $objQuery->bindValue(':username', $username);
        $objQuery->execute();
        $row         = $objQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!empty($row)) {
            if($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password']) {
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                $_SESSION['username']  = $row['username'];
                header('Location: i/');
            } else
                header('Location: index.php?err=true&type=1');
        } else
            header('Location: index.php?err=true&type=2');
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}

?>
```

I always get error 2 - account not found. I'm logging in with user "test" and password "test". In the database is an account with username "test" and the password is an MD5 hash of "test".

Comment: Remove the quotes from `':username'` - binding the variable will take care of that for you

Answer (score 3):

Your sql statement is wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=':username'
```

You should not put your placeholder in quotes as now it is taken literally by mysql.

It should be:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username
```

You should also tell PDO to throw exceptions:

```
$opt = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$objDatabase = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $opt);
```

So that it will tell you when something goes wrong.

**Edit:** As noted by @LozCheroneツ you also need to execute the query before you can fetch a row:

```
$objQuery->bindValue(':username', $username);
$objQuery->execute();
```

Comment: Changed it to `$objQuery = $objDatabase->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");` but I still get the account not found error

Comment: @jeroen hes also missing `execute()`

Comment: @Will See my edit about throwing exceptions and LozCheroneツ's comment.

Comment: @Will What error do you get? Also, get rid of the redirections `header` calls while you are debugging so that you can see what happens.

Comment: I still get "Account not found"